# python fn = sys.argv[1] meaning in code (spyder)

Tags: python, image-processing, spyder

I'm currently learning Python in spyder software and was just wondering (In reference to my example below) in simplified terms what the sys.argv[1] represents. Is it simply asking for an input?

````
    import sys

    fn = sys.argv[1]

    filename = os.path.split(fn)[-1].split(".")[0]
    filepath = os.path.split(fn)[0]

    src = cv2.imread(fn)
    # read the image```

>IndexError: list index out of range
````

Comment: `sys.argv` is a list of command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` is a List of Command Line argument.
from the terminal you type: `python path/to/your_script.py path/to/the_image.jpg`
then the sys.argv List would be: `["path/to/your_script.py", "path/to/the_image.jpg"]`
in your case: sys.argv[1] refers to the image file which cv2 should read (ie: `"path/to/the_image.jpg"`).